# How to read http request query enclosed inside angle brackets

Tags: node.js, express, url, parameters, xmlhttprequest

From a url like `www.shop/customer?names=girl(a,b)&names=boy(c,d)`, I want to extract information like `girl:a,b` and `boy:c,d` in JSON? Is there any built in function?